# How to hide the title bar in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, taskbar, titlebar

I was wondering does anyone know how to hide the pygame task bar?

I really need this for my pygame program!

Thanks!

Comment: What is this task bar of which you speak?

Comment: The [OS taskbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar) or the window's [title bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_bar)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `pygame.NOFRAME`:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.NOFRAME)
```

[The documentation](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) says:

> `pygame.NOFRAME       display window will have no border or controls`