# Change the color of a pygame window title bar

Tags: python, colors, pygame, background, background-color

I am currently programming the Snake game with Python 3.7.0. I use pygame. I am new to Python and I don't know how to change the color since the background itself is black and the "Window Bar" on top of it is also black. This makes it hard to see where the field is over. I am not sure if it's even possible to do but if someone know a way please let me know. For the picture I changed the background color sou you can see what I mean [This is the Game. Usually it has a Black background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KFcG.png)

This is the code I am currently using:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
 
pygame.init()
 
white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)
 
dis_width = 600
dis_height = 400
 
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 15
 
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("8514oem.fon", 40)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("8514oem.fon", 30)
 
def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, white, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])
 
 
def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])
 
 
def gameLoop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False
 
    x1 = dis_width / 2
    y1 = dis_height / 2
 
    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0
 
    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1
 
    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
 
    while not game_over:
 
        while game_close == True:
            dis.fill(red)
            message("GAME OVER", white)
 
            pygame.display.update()
 
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        gameLoop()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        gameLoop()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        gameLoop() 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
 
        if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        dis.fill(red)
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, green, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]
 
        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True
 
        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
 
 
        pygame.display.update()
 
        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
 
        clock.tick(snake_speed)
 
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
 
 
gameLoop()
```

Code from https://www.edureka.co/blog/snake-game-with-pygame/#install
I just changed it so it is better for me.

Best Regards
-Sandro

Comment: Your operating system, specifically the window manager will control the appearance of the title bar of your application. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383803/2280890) shows how to disable the frame completely by passing `pygame.NOFRAME` to the `set_mode(...)` call. You could disable the native title bar and then construct your own if you still want customisation.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used pygame too much myself but I remember reading something like the following might help

```
color = input("Choose a background color: ")
if color == "red":
    screen.fill(red)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Not 100% sure if this is right

Comment: This doesen't change the title bar of the window. It changes the background but that's not what I want.

Comment: Sorry I mis-read your question. It's probably just easier to hide the window bar, rather than change color:
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.NOFRAME)

Comment: Yes, I did it almost like that. But instead of NOFRAME I put it in FULLSCREEN. That worked for me :D